# Starting a Qt5 console app: invokemethod vs singleshot timer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have seen two different ways of starting a Qt console application by calling a class method when the event loop starts. [This way](https://jimloco.com/2011/02/18/writing-a-console-application-with-qt/) queues a method to be invoked as soon as the event loop starts, and [this way](http://www.tomhuang.com/2015/07/12/how-to-implement-a-console-type-application-in-qt5.html) runs a singleShot timer that triggers a slot to execute shortly after the event loop starts. In both cases, the goal is to get the event loop running before executing the class method.

Neither of these seem especially clean to me, but I haven't seen anything better. I also don't have much experience with Qt, so who am I to say?

Is there an advantage to either way? The invokeMethod way (the first link) doesn't seem to be as common as the singleShot timer way (the second link), but aside from that I have no reason to follow one pattern over the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QTimer::singleShot()` has an overload that takes a function pointer (member function, functor or lambda).

Using this overload will provide compile time check, which is better than the run time check you get when using the function name. Moreover the called function is not required to be a slot.

As of Qt 5.8, there are no such overload for `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` so you are stuck to call slots using their names. Note that this feature will be added in Qt 5.10.

IMHO the compile time check is enough for using `QTimer::singleShot()` (and leaving aside `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` until 5.10 is out).

Also as @Jeremy pointed out, calling `QTimer::singleShot()` with a delay of 0 ms ends up calling `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`, but only if you are using the overload that takes a slot name (so no compile time check). The overload of `QTimer::singleShot()` that takes a function pointers has no such optimization for 0 ms cases and may take a little more CPU and memory to set up.

To sum up:

```
MyObject *object;

// 1: No compile time check for slot1, may fail at run time if slot1() does not exist
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "slot1", Qt::QueuedConnection);

// 2: Calls 1 internally, but needs to do dome string editing to remove the decoration added by SLOT()
QTimer::singleShot(0, object, SLOT(slot1()));

// 3: Compile time check (i.e slot1() must exist), but creates a QSingleShotTimer internally (maybe less optimized)
QTimer::singleShot(0, object, &MyObject::slot1);
// QTimer::singleShot(0, [&](){printf("\o/"); object->slot1();}); // It can also call lambda 

// In any case, slot1 will be called as soon as event processing starts
app.exec()
```

Comment: You might update this answer with respect to Qt 5.10 having been out for some time now.

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty much the same thing; so it really comes down to which syntax you find more natural to use.

In particular, let's look at Qt's implementation of QTimer::singleShot(0, ...) (note:  I removed some error-checking in the code, for better clarity):

```
 void QTimer::singleShot(int msec, Qt::TimerType timerType, const QObject *receiver, const char *member)
 {
     if (receiver && member) {
         if (msec == 0) {
             // special code shortpath for 0-timers
             const char* bracketPosition = strchr(member, '(');
             QByteArray methodName(member+1, bracketPosition - 1 - member); // extract method name
             QMetaObject::invokeMethod(const_cast<QObject *>(receiver), methodName.constData(), Qt::QueuedConnection);
             return;
         }
         [...]
     }
 }
```

As you can see, QTimer::singleShot(0, ...) is really just calling invokeMethod() for you anyway.